# Why does my sub break on a VarType print on Mac/M1?

Tags: vba, macos

I have a variable declared as a string.
Does the Debug.Print function affects the variable? Why doesn't it already break at `publicVariable = 100`

This doesn't work:

```
Option Explicit

'Declare a public modul-level Variable
Public publicVariable As String

'Declare a modul-level Variable
Private privateVariable As String

'Declare a modul-level Variable with Dim
Dim privateVariableDim As String

'Initiate Sub
Sub rumbleBumbleVariables():

'Declare a procedure-level Variable
Dim procedureVariable As String

'Declare a procedure-level Variable which is static between calls
Static staticVariable As String

publicVariable = 100
Debug.Print VarType(publicVariable)

publicVariable = publicVariable + 1

Debug.Print VarType(publicVariable)
Debug.Print publicVariable

End Sub
```

Doesn't break:

```
Option Explicit

'Declare a public modul-level Variable
Public publicVariable As String

'Declare a modul-level Variable
Private privateVariable As String

'Declare a modul-level Variable with Dim
Dim privateVariableDim As String

'Initiate Sub
Sub rumbleBumbleVariables():

'Declare a procedure-level Variable
Dim procedureVariable As String

'Declare a procedure-level Variable which is static between calls
Static staticVariable As String

publicVariable = 100

publicVariable = publicVariable + 1

Debug.Print VarType(publicVariable)
Debug.Print publicVariable

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unable to reproduce. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuFMu.png

Comment: @BigBen I added the entire code

Comment: Still unable to reproduce. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU7SB.png What do you expect to "break"?

Comment: huhh? I dont get it, it breaks on my end

Comment: How does it 'break'?

Comment: Ah - you're on Mac I see.

Comment: Yes, 64bit / M1 - does that cause it?

Comment: Most likely related yes, though I'm not sure what exactly is causing the issue.

Comment: @Jonas your doing math w/ a string, try correctly typing the variable to `integer`? Just a guess, I'm surprised it doesn't error on PC.